# Cant get redirect to work in Asp.net WebApi

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller that redirects:

```
 var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);

 response.Headers.Add("Location",
     "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + pars["oauth_token"]
     + "&oauth_callback=http://localhost:2638/index.html#/tasks/compose-task/");

 return response;
```

and call it from javascript:

```
    $.ajax("/api/dropbox/get_request_token", { dataType: 'json' })
    .done(function (data)
    {
        alert(ko.toJSON(data));
    })
    .fail(function (err) {alert(ko.toJSON(err));});
```

The network tab shows:

```
GET http://localhost:2638/api/dropbox/get_request_token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:2638/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1337.0 Safari/537.20
```

but it never redirects to dropbox.com. instead it ends up in the fail().

Am i missing something?

Comment: The network tab says canceled. the alert box says responsetext:""; readystate:0;statustext:error;status:0

Comment: @s093294: You shouldn't use AJAX for a an API that returns a Redirect response. Instead, make the API return the url as a string, and redirect the user using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a property for "Location" header. Try:

```
response.Headers.Location = new Uri( "http://google.com");
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is the same as what i was doing. Same results.

Comment: I am thinking the issue is because of not calling the web api properly. $.ajax() ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set your HttpStatusCode to Redirect, like so:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);

response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.dropbox.com");

return response;
```

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302